# No rate-limiting delay on first review in a queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, rate-limiting

*The problem is exactly what it says on the tin:*

When I am on https://stackoverflow.com/review and I click on a review queue (Say, [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)), here is no delay whatsoever on Accept/Reject/etc for the first item to review. Only on the second item are the non-Skip buttons disabled for a couple seconds.

This is a problem; In particular, this means that I am capable of making a decision on the first item that I am presented with in a queue without the usual rate-limiting time-out. Worse, it appears to me that it is exploitable, as you could go almost arbitrarily fast with a loop consisting of

1. Enter the [Close Queue (stackoverflow.com/review/close)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close)
2. Vote "Accept" immediately.
3. Before timeout is over,

   - Click your toolbar bookmark bound to [stackoverflow.com/review/close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).
   - **Or**, Delete the trailing /number from e.g. [stackoverflow.com/review/close/6939105](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6939105) in your browser's URL bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. `goto` 2.

Step 3 is crucial, since it makes it "appear" that you're newly referred from the review page, you're not given a time delay (again & again & again & again).

In short, when I'm redirected from [/review/close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) to any particular item (e.g. [/review/close/6939105](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6939105), there seems to be no rate-limitng delay whatsoever on Accepts, but if going from an item ([/review/close/6939105](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6939105))) to the next ([/review/close/6939562](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6939562)) by conventional means, there is. And this is problematic because nothing stops you from immediately loading [/review/close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), which redirects to another item, usually faster than the time-delay.

The only thing that appears to stop me is the speed of my Internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug, although if you wanted to make a feature request for more strict rate-limiting of review submissions you certainly could.

As for *why* it's not a bug... The UI is just a suggestion. It's handy for preventing inadvertent double-clicks from leading to inadvertent reviews, and it's a nice *hint* that you should maybe slow down and read the review you're looking at... But nothing more.

Heck, if you *really* wanted to abuse it you could trivially write a script to submit reviews of dozens of posts a minute without even bothering to load them! Of course, that'd be wrong, and anyone caught doing that would likely find themselves banned from review for a good long while.

Comment: True enough, though my skills at scripting are lacking, while those at clicking fast aren't. I'd wager more people are capable of doing the proposed sequence of clicks than there are who would code up such a script. This was a report I made because I thought it could help; If this is by design, then that's that, but still, I find it odd the first review can be done instantly.

Comment: Like I said, feel free to propose more strict rate limits here - the real solution would have to be server-side, just as existing rate-limits (for posts, comments, votes, etc.) are.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Seeing as this is a site used mainly by programmers I think you'd find that quite a large portion of the userbase is perfectly capable of writing such a script. And those who are not wouldn't have much of a problem finding somewhere to ask for help ;)